# Is there a way to know from which a form is opened?

Tags: forms, dynamics-crm

I work on Dynamics-crm 2016 version, I need to know from where a form is opened (grid, button etc) in ON-PREMISSE dynamics 2016, is it optional to get that data?

Comment: What’s your original problem? There may be a different easy solution for that problem instead of this

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in multiple ways. My simple suggestion: Add a boolean field on the form, set it default to false. Add some javascript that subscribes to the forms onLoad event. The logic changes the bool value to true. Thus when the form is loaded (opened), the JS code runs and sets the field to true. You can also timestamp it and set it to readonly.